# jQuery pulsating code conflicting with scrolling image jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

This is the website: http://test.designpro.digingage.com/

Before I added the pulsating image, the middle scrolling images worked.  This is my pulsating image code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function pulsate() {
        $(".phone").animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 1200, 'linear')
                     .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1200, 'linear', pulsate)
                     .click(function() {
                         $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1200, 'linear');
                         $(this).stop();
                     });
        }

    pulsate();
});
```

I'm not sure which .js file this is conflicting with... is there a noConflict code that I could use so that both items work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest from a design point of view not to have that pulsating at all. But when exactly does it break, if you take out that code right there, does the slider begin to work again?

Also, change the class for the pulsating image, as it's pulsating the phone number form field as well. Unless that's what you want to happen.